# Response Content type as CSV

Tags: asp.net, http, csv

I need to send a CSV file in HTTP response. How can I set the output response as CSV format?

This is not working:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/CSV";
```

Answer (score 580, accepted):

Using `text/csv` is the most appropriate type.

You should also consider adding a `Content-Disposition` header to the response.  Often a text/csv will be loaded by a Internet Explorer directly into a hosted instance of Excel.  This may or may not be a desirable result.

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=myfilename.csv");
```

The above will cause a file "Save as" dialog to appear which may be what you intend.

Comment: I like to use a System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition object for building that string.

Answer (score 205):

MIME type of the CSV is `text/csv` according to [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180).

Answer (score 84):

Use `text/csv` as the content type.

Answer (score 55):

Over the years I've been honing a perfect set of headers for this that work brilliantly in all browsers that I know of

```
// these headers avoid IE problems when using https:
// see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812935
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: must-revalidate");

header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.csv");
```

Comment: If you use application/vnd.ms-excel. On osx safari adds a ".xls" file extension

Comment: The `Pragma`  header is [deprecated by now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Pragma).

Answer (score 30):

Try one of these other mime-types (from here: http://filext.com/file-extension/CSV )

- text/comma-separated-values
- text/csv
- application/csv
- application/excel
- application/vnd.ms-excel
- application/vnd.msexcel

Also, the mime-type *might* be case sensitive...

Answer (score 15):

Just Use like that

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/CSV";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + ".csv\"");
Response.Write(t.ToString());
Response.End();
```

Comment: Enclosing the file name in double quotes fixed this for me when the client is Firefox.

Comment: If you're using this in an MVC controller, you'll need to end the controller method with `return new EmptyResult()` to get the filename to stick. Otherwise IE will try and save the file as `ActionName.htm`.

Answer (score 5):

In ASP.net MVC, you can use a `FileContentResult` and the `File` method:

```
public FileContentResult DownloadManifest() {
    byte[] csvData = getCsvData();
    return File(csvData, "text/csv", "filename.csv");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have found that the problem with IE is that it sniffs the return data and makes up its own mind about what content-type it thinks it has been sent. There are a number of side effect that this causes, such as always openning a saveAs dialog for text files because you are using compression of data trasnferes. The solution is (in php code)......

```
header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to insert an '/' character in front of 'myfilename.cvs'

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=/myfilename.csv");
```

I hope you get better results.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the content type and the content disposition as described above produces wildly varying results with different browsers:

IE8: SaveAs dialog as desired, and Excel as the default app.  100% good.

Firefox: SaveAs dialog does show up, but Firefox has no idea it is a spreadsheet.  Suggests opening it with Visual Studio!  50% good

Chrome: the hints are fully ignored.  The CSV data is shown in the browser.  0% good.

Of course in all of these cases I'm referring to the browsers as they come out of they box, with no customization of the mime/application mappings.

Comment: If Firefox wants you to open with Visual Studio, means you are exporting the HTML and not a CSV.

Comment: This does not appear to be the case in 2014, it worked fine in all of them for me.

Comment: Please define "as described above"

Answer (score 0):

For C# MVC 4.5 you need to do like this:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/CSV";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + ".csv\"");
Response.Write(dataNeedToPrint);
Response.End();
return new EmptyResult();  //this line is important else it will not work.
```