# .csv file opens as HTML document

Tags: download

All,

In my application i allow users to download a csv file  from the App.  When a user clicks on the Download file link , they see the Download file dialog box. My problem is that some o f the files opens as an HTML document.This happens intermittently.This is the code am using.Can anyone please help?

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"; 
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition"
  , "attachment; filename=" + sf.FileName);
Response.OutputStream.Write(sf.Data, 0, sf.Data.Length);
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
```

I tried `Response.End()` insted of `Response.Flush();`  but didnt help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

THanks

RJ

Comment: Please indent your code with four spaces and use normal formatting and newlines.

Comment: Forget about what you think you're doing - what headers actually get sent back? Use Firefox's Live HTTP Headers or the net tab in firebug to find out.

Answer (score 2):

text/csv is more appropriate.

see: [Response Content type as CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393647/response-content-type-as-csv)