# OpenXML file download without temporary file

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml, openxml-sdk

Is there a way of providing a download in an ASP.Net Page for a freshly generated OpenXML (docx) file without saving it in a temporary folder?

On [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469465%28v=office.12%29.aspx) I only found a tutorial for using a temp file but I thought about using the `WordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()` and directly writing the stream out.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393647/response-content-type-as-csv You should be able to use the same solution by writing your data directly to the response.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you create the document use a `MemoryStream` as the backing store.  Then create and close the document normally and serve the contents of the memory stream to the client.

```
using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using(var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(stream, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, true) 
    {
        ...
    }
    stream.Position = 0;
    stream.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream);
}
```

Do not just grab the `MainDocumentPart` because, as the name implies, this is just one part of the document package, not everything.

You'll also need to set response headers for content type and disposition.

Answer (score 1):

[Stream.CopyTo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto.aspx) in .NET 4.0 might help you out here.

```
WordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.GetStream().CopyTo(Response.OutputStream);
```

You'll still need to set the headers for MIME type, content-disposition and so on.