# Open XML Make excel viewable

Tags: excel, openxml

I'm using Open XML to open an excel file as in:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument myWorkbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Open("generated.xlsx", true))
```

...

but I cannot figure out how to actually launch excel and show the file through code.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at either one of these answers:

[how to create and download excel document using asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643643/how-to-create-and-download-excel-document-using-asp-net)

[OpenXML file download without temporary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710290/openxml-file-download-without-temporary-file)