# Streaming OpenXML result

Tags: openxml

By using *OpenXML* to manipulating a *Word* document (as a template), the server application saves the new content as a temporary file and then sends it to user to download.

The question is how to make these content ready to download without saving it on the server as a temporary file? Is it possible to save *OpenXML* result as a `byte[]` or `Stream` instead of saving it as a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this page:
[OpenXML file download without temporary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710290/openxml-file-download-without-temporary-file)

I changed my code to this one:

```cs
byte[] result = null;
byte[] templateBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(wordTemplate);
using (MemoryStream templateStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    templateStream.Write(templateBytes, 0, (int)templateBytes.Length);
    using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(templateStream, true))
    {
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;           
        ...         
        mainPart.Document.Save();
        templateStream.Position = 0;
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            templateStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            result = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's only for download no need to convert to byte[]. Just set stream location to 0.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the WordprocessingDocument and then use the `Save()` method to save it to a `Stream`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc882497

Answer (score 1):

```
  var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
  document.Clone(memoryStream);
```