# PHP Creating CSV not working as expected

Tags: php, export-to-csv

i'm trying to create a CSV using this solution:
[Creating csv file with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501463/creating-csv-file-with-php)

Something is wrong, i keep getting data stuffed into one cell like this:

[image]

each value should be in an own cell .. any ideas what's wrong?
seems like the csv uses the wrong delimiter.

thanks

Comment: It is working fine at my end. I opened file in Excel 2007. which version are you trying? Or, try to open this generated CSV to any other PC. May be some setting changed in your excel.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution: seems like it doesn't work for the German version of Excel,
all I had to do is changing the delimiter to a semi-colon like this:

```
fputcsv($fp, $val, ";");
```

Comment: I remember a question being posted some time ago where it was the same problem. OP was using a German version of Excel. The issue was quickly resolved because the OP had posted that they were using a German version which made answering/solving the issue faster.