# PHP variables to excel spreadsheet

Tags: php, excel, screen-scraping

I have the following code which scrapes the text from multiple pages and displays them.

My question for you is how can I take each of those variables and place them into an excel spreadsheet located on the server. For each link, on separate rows.

Like this : [image]

```js
<?php
include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$urls = array(
 'http://lmvz.anofm.ro:8080/lmv/detalii.jsp?UNIQUEJVID=50/01/1150001435/1&judet=50',
 'http://lmvz.anofm.ro:8080/lmv/detalii.jsp?UNIQUEJVID=50/05/1140001657/1&judet=50',
 'http://lmvz.anofm.ro:8080/lmv/detalii.jsp?UNIQUEJVID=50/05/1140001657/2&judet=50',
 'http://lmvz.anofm.ro:8080/lmv/detalii.jsp?UNIQUEJVID=50/01/1150001435/1&judet=50',
 'http://lmvz.anofm.ro:8080/lmv/detalii.jsp?UNIQUEJVID=50/05/1140001657/1&judet=50',
 'http://lmvz.anofm.ro:8080/lmv/detalii.jsp?UNIQUEJVID=50/05/1140001657/2&judet=50',
 'http://lmvz.anofm.ro:8080/lmv/detalii.jsp?UNIQUEJVID=50/01/1150001435/1&judet=50',
 'http://lmvz.anofm.ro:8080/lmv/detalii.jsp?UNIQUEJVID=50/05/1140001657/1&judet=50',
 'http://lmvz.anofm.ro:8080/lmv/detalii.jsp?UNIQUEJVID=50/05/1140001657/2&judet=50',
);
function scraping($url) {
 // DOM
 
 $html = file_get_html($url);
 
 // articol
 if ($html && is_object($html) && isset($html->nodes)) {
 
  foreach ($html->find('/html/body/table') as $article) {
   //titlu
 
   $item['titlu'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[1]/td/div', 0)->plaintext);
 
   // tabel
   $item['tr2'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]', 0)->plaintext);
   $item['tr3'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]', 0)->plaintext);
   $item['tr4'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]', 0)->plaintext);
   $item['tr5'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]', 0)->plaintext);
   $item['tr6'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]', 0)->plaintext);
   $item['tr7'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]', 0)->plaintext);
   $item['tr8'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]', 0)->plaintext);
   $item['tr9'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]', 0)->plaintext);
   $item['tr10'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[10]/td[2]', 0)->plaintext);
   $item['tr11'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[11]/td[2]', 0)->plaintext);
   $item['tr12'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[12]/td/div/]', 0)->plaintext);
   $ret[] = $item;
  }
 
  // memorie
  $html->clear();
  unset($html);
 
  return $ret;}
}
echo '<pre>';
 
foreach ($urls as $url) {
 $ret = scraping($url);
 
 foreach ($ret as $v) {
  echo $v['titlu'] . '<br>';
 
  echo $v['tr2'] . '<br>';
  echo $v['tr3'] . '<br>';
  echo $v['tr4'] . '<br>';
  echo $v['tr5'] . '<br>';
  echo $v['tr6'] . '<br>';
  echo $v['tr7'] . '<br>';
  echo $v['tr8'] . '<br>';
  echo $v['tr9'] . '<br>';
  echo $v['tr10'] . '<br>';
  echo $v['tr11'] . '<br>';
  echo $v['tr12'] . '<br>';
  echo '<br>';
        echo '<br>';
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be easier to do with a CSV file which you can later import into Excel?

Comment: Sure, just give me the code please.

Comment: more info on CSV here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501463/creating-csv-file-with-php