# Create comma delimited .csv file with php

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to:

1. create comma delimited .csv file with php code.
2. Insert column name in the first line of the .csv file.

Please advise how can I make this happen.

```
    <?php

    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$batch_id.".csv");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");   

    $conn_sp = mssql_connect("SQLServer", "user", "password"); 
    $db_sp = mssql_select_db("databaseName", $conn_sp); 
    $stmt = mssql_init("[StoredProcedureName]",$conn_sp);       
    mssql_bind($stmt, "@BatchNo", $batch_id, SQLVARCHAR, FALSE, FALSE, 20);     
    $result = mssql_query("SET ANSI_NULLS ON"); 
    $result = mssql_query("SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON");      
    $result = mssql_execute($stmt);
    $record="";
    $comma=",";
    $record_end="\n";
    while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($result, MSSQL_ASSOC)){ 

    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {      

          echo $value;      
        }
        echo "\n";  

    }?>
```

! [image]

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating csv file with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501463/creating-csv-file-with-php)

Comment: I tried these articles but didn't work. Not sure but I am doing wrong, so please if you can advise on the above code, I will appreciate. Thank you!

Comment: First thing first, if you remove the headers, then you got something right?...can you post the output you are getting?

Comment: Please see the output of the code

Comment: Show how the `fputcsv` failed for you. It should be clear why you don't have  a CSV currently (Hint: defining a variable doesn't cause it to do anything `$comma`).

Answer (score 0):

Well just look at how a .csv-file is created.

Usually like this:

Delimiter: ,

New line: \n

Enclose entry by: "

e.g.

> "r1a","r1b","r1c"
>
> "r2a","r2b","r2c"
>
> etc...

This is how your code should work (untested):

```
         echo '"colname1","colname2",...';

         while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($result, MSSQL_ASSOC)){ 
        
            $first = true;
            foreach ($row as $key => $value) {      
    
                if(!$first) {
                     echo ",";
                }
        
                  echo '"'.$value.'"';      
                }
                echo "\n";  
                $first=false;
            }
```

Comment: Don't make your own CSV parser. What if `$value` has double quotes, commas?

Comment: So, what's the best way to go, Chris? Can u please share example? Thank you!

Comment: @Paul Please use the `@` to tag users, notifications aren't sent otherwise. You should use the built in option, http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php. There are examples on that page. If you are having issues with that post your usage and what happens.

Comment: @chris85 In most cases this own .csv parser will do perfectly well. The only issue I can think of is with double quotes - it can be solved like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808511/properly-escape-a-double-quote-in-csv