# How could I write an array into a csv-file?

Tags: php, curl

I generate an array of several variables and want to write entirely this into a csv-file. The header works correctly but from the array only /\n/"(, is written into the csv.

If I use `implode` before **echo**, then I get an empty line.
What's wrong? here is the code I'm using so far:

```
<?php

    function scrape_between($data, $start, $end){
        $data = stristr($data, $start); 
        $data = substr($data, strlen($start)); 
        $stop = stripos($data, $end); 
        $data = substr($data, 0, $stop); 
        return $data; 
    }

    function curl($url) {

        $options = Array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE, 
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120,
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1a2pre) Gecko/2008073000 Shredder/3.0a2pre ThunderBrowse/3.2.1.8",  // Setting the useragent
            CURLOPT_URL => $url, 
        );

        $ch = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options); 
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);   
        return $data; 
    };

    $header = 'date1,date2,contractcode,exchange,region,commoditycode,openint,noncomlong,noncomshort,noncomspread,comlong,comshort,';
    echo($header);

    $scraped_page = curl("https://www.cftc.gov/dea/newcot/deafut.txt");   
    $scraped_wheat = scrape_between($scraped_page, "WHEAT-SRW - CHICAGO BOARD OF TRADE", "CONTRACTS");
    $scraped_wheat = preg_replace('/",/', '', $scraped_wheat); 
    $pieces = explode('WHEAT', $scraped_wheat);  
    $items = explode(",",$pieces[0]); 
    $tmp = 0;
    foreach ($items as $value)if ($tmp++ < 12) {
    $value = preg_replace('/\s/', '', $value);
    echo ($value.",");

    };
    $file = 'cot-zw.csv';
    file_put_contents($file, $header.'/\n/'.$value.",");

?>
```

Thank you very much for your help!

**EDIT**

The suggestions via `fputcsv` produces an empty csv-file. Thats what I tried (and failed):

````
    $scraped_wheat = scrape_between($scraped_page, "WHEAT-SRW - CHICAGO BOARD OF TRADE", "CONTRACTS");
    $scraped_wheat = preg_replace('/",/', '', $scraped_wheat);  // ", am Anfang entfernen
    $pieces = explode('WHEAT', $scraped_wheat);  // explode() Teilt die Zeichenkette
    $items = explode(",",$pieces[0]); // Definition des , als Teiler
    $tmp = 0;
    foreach ($items as $value)if ($tmp++ < 12) {
    $value = preg_replace('/\s/', '', $value);
    echo ($value.",");    
    $fp = fopen('cot-zw.csv', 'w');
    foreach($value as $line){
             $val = explode(",",$line);
             fputcsv($fp, $val);
    }
    fclose($fp);   
    };```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating csv file with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501463/creating-csv-file-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

`file_put_contents()` is a really cruddy way to write to a csv.

I'd recommend using `fputcsv()`. Here's a very simple example:

```
<?php
$csv_items = [
    ['row1-col1','row1-col2','row1-col3'],
    ['row2-col1','row2-col2','row2-col3'],
    ['row3-col1','row3-col2','row3-col3']
];

if( $fh = fopen('file.csv','w') ){

    foreach( $csv_items as $csv_item ){
        fputcsv($fh, $csv_item);
    }

    fclose( $fh );
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? Using `fputcsv()` over `file_put_contentes()` is the most obvious solution

Comment: I'm sorry but these sulutions do nothing. (I tried all of them anyway...)

Comment: As far as I understand, the `echo ($value.",");` echoes the whole foreach-loop. How  can I put this entire loop into the csv?