# Streaming CSV to browser

Tags: csv, asp-classic

Busy building a website for a client using classic ASP (It will reside on an old server) which is going to be used internally only.

The admin is able to view a paginated table of data and export this to CSV. This works fine when I save the CSV data to a CSV file but I have now been asked to try avoid the creation of the file if possibly and create the CSV in memory without the need for a file.

I have my doubts that this is possible but might be completely wrong. Is there anyway to send the CSV data to the browser such that it will open in Excel rather than having to create a CSV file and link to it as I am currently doing ?

TIA
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Response.ContentType = "text/csv"` will help you here. In the past I've paired that with a rewrite rule so that the URL is something like foo.com/example.csv but there are plenty of other ideas to be found in the following question: [Response Content type as CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393647/response-content-type-as-csv)