# Why can´t Firefox Browser this File not attach in right way?

Tags: java, csv

i have a problem with the following java code:

```
    final FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    final ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();

    response.setContentType("text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachement;filename=result.csv");
    final OutputStream outputSteam = response.getOutputStream();

    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputSteam, "ISO-8859-1"), ';', '"');

    // Fill the csv file with something 

    writer.close();
    outputSteam.flush();
    outputSteam.close();
```

I have a system, this can be export some file into a csv format, which shuld be refered with MS Excel. Sometimes it is possible, that the table calculation programm will not start automatically, if the user save the csv export file on his computer hard disk. In this way, the file are not a "result.csv" file, but a "result.csv.txt" file. But why? The problem exist only with firefox browser, bur not in IE.

Does anything missing in the java code? Any feature or something? Or is this a only windows internal problem, which are not provoke by my java code?

Thanks for help !

Greetz
Marwief

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the ContentType to text/csv  instead of text/plain.

Also, see [Response Content type as CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393647/response-content-type-as-csv)